# How can I Add/Edit on same page in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There are two types of data I'm displaying on single page, one is Insert form and second is where the data is displayed with the help of Angular dataTables, now what I want to do is when I click on Edit I wana display the Data within the Insert form Fields also change the Save button from Save to Update... I've tried it but I'm getting this error although its displaying the data in console.

```
controller.js:1356 24
controller.js:1363 Colony 02 2
angular-1.4.8.js:12520 TypeError: Cannot set property 'colony_name' of undefined
```

**NOTE: Insert, Delete, Displaying Data is working fine.**

**Here is my HTML PAGE**

```
<div class="row-fluid" ng-controller="colony_Controller">
<div class="span12">

    <div class="span6">

        <!-- WIDGET START -->
        <div class="widget TwoWidgetsInOneFix">

            <!-- Widget Title Start -->
            <div class="widget-title">
                <h4><i class="icon-reorder"></i>Add Colony</h4>
                <span class="tools">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-chevron-down"></a>
                    <!-- <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-remove"></a> -->
                </span>
            </div>
            <!-- Widget Title End -->

            <!-- Widget Body Start -->
            <div class="widget-body">

                <form class="form-horizontal">

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="small-bg-half">
                            <label class="control-label">Colony Name</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="" autofocus required name="colony_name"
                                ng-model="field.colony_name" > <!-- ng-->
                                <span class="help-inline" id="help-inline" style="color:red;"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="small-bg-half">
                            <label class="control-label">Colony Type</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <select data-toggle="status" class="select select-default mrs mbm input-xlarge" name="colony_type" id="colony_type" ng-model="field.colony_type_id" required> <!-- ng -->
                                    <option value="">--Select Colony Type--</option>
                                    <option ng-repeat="colony in es_colony_type" value="{{colony.es_colony_type_id}}">{{colony.es_colony_type_name}}</option>

                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-actions">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="InsertData()"> <!-- ng -->
                            <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Save</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
            <!-- Widget Body End -->

        </div>
        <!-- WIDGET END -->

    </div>

    <div class="span6">

        <!-- WIDGET START -->
        <div class="widget TwoWidgetsInOneFix">

            <!-- Widget Title Start -->
            <div class="widget-title"> <!-- ng -->
                <h4><i class="icon-reorder"></i>List Of Colony</h4>
                <span class="tools">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-chevron-down"></a>
                    <!-- <a href="javascript:;" class="icon-remove"></a> -->
                </span>
            </div>
            <!-- Widget Title End -->

            <!-- <div id="alert-2" flash-alert active-class="in alert" class="fade">
                <strong class="alert-heading">Boo!</strong>
                <span class="alert-message">{{flash.message}}</span>
            </div> -->

            <!-- Widget Body Start -->
            <div class="widget-body">

                <div ng-controller="colony_Controller as Main_Module">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" align="center" datatable="" dt-options="Main_Module.dtOptions" dt-columns="Main_Module.dtColumns" class="row-border hover">
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- Widget Body End -->

    </div>
    <!-- WIDGET END -->

</div>
```

**Here is my Controller**

```
Main_Module.controller('colony_Controller', function add_house_Controller(flash, $window, $scope, $http, $compile, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, bootbox, SimpleHttpRequest, DelMainRecPicRecUnlinkPic, message)
{   
            $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/SELECT/es_colony_type').success(function(data)
    {
        $scope.es_colony_type = data.es_colony_type;
    });
    /********************************** FETCH DATA END *********************************/

    /********************************** INSERT DATA START ********************************/
    $scope.InsertData = function()
    {
        var values = $scope.field;

        SimpleHttpRequest.Insert('POST','INSERT', 'es_colony', values)
        .then(function successCallback(response)
        {
            if(!response.data.Error)
            {
                message.successMessageForInsert("<strong>Successfull !</strong> Colony Details Inserted");
                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    $window.location.reload();
                }, 3500);

                // flash.to('alert-1').success = 'Only for alert 1';                                
            }
            else
            {
                message.failedMessageForInsert("<strong>Error !</strong> Data Insertion Failed");
            }
        },
        function errorCallback(response)
        {
            message.failedMessageForInsert("<strong>Error!</strong> Data Insertion Failed !");
        });       
    };
    /********************************** INSERT DATA END **********************************/

    /********************************** DISPLAY DATA START *******************************/
    var vm = this;
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
    .fromFnPromise(function()
    {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/SELECT/es_colony')
        .then(function(response)
        {
            return response.data.es_colony;
        });
    })
    .withOption('order', [0, 'asc'])
    .withDisplayLength(5)
    .withPaginationType('simple_numbers')
    .withOption('createdRow', function(row, data, dataIndex)
    {
        $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
    })
    vm.dtColumns =
    [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('es_colony_name').withTitle('Colony'),            
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Actions').notSortable().withOption('width', '31%')
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta)
        {
            return '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="edit_records(' + data.es_colony_id + ')">' +
                   '<i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit' + '</button>&nbsp;' +
                   '<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="DeleteRecord(' + data.es_colony_id + ')">' +
                   '<i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i> Delete' + '</button>';
        })
    ];

    /********************************** DISPLAY DATA END *********************************/

    /********************************** DELETE DATA START ********************************/
    // $scope.hideRow = [];
    $scope.DeleteRecord = function(id)
    {
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record ?", function (confirmation)
        {
            if(confirmation)
            {
                DelMainRecPicRecUnlinkPic.DeleteIt('', id, true, 'es_colony', 'es_colony_id')
                {
                    setTimeout(function()
                    {
                        $window.location.reload();
                    }, 3500);
                };
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.edit_records = function(id)
    {
        // PassId.id = id;
        console.log(id);

        SimpleHttpRequest.SelectByID('GET', 'SELECTBYID', 'es_colony', 'es_colony_id', id)
        .then(function successCallback(response)
        {
            var data = response.data.es_colony[0];

            console.log(data.es_colony_name, data.es_colony_type_id);    

            $scope.ufield.ucolony_name = data.es_colony_name;
            $scope.ufield.colony_type_id = data.es_colony_type_id;
        });
    };
    /********************************** DELETE DATA END **********************************/

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your template, you have an input with `ng-model="field.colony_name"`, but in your controller you never defined `$scope.field`. You do assign the value `var values = $scope.field` inside the `$scope.InsertData` function, but that will just set `values` to `undefined`.

Try initializing the variable by adding `$scope.field = {}` to the beginning of your controller, for starters. That will resolve the error you are getting.

Comment: Hey Thanks, the Error Problem is gone, but still I don't know why the data is displayed in the fields. :(

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Are you loading data from $http that you want to display in the input field? Because there is a problem with how you're fetching data in the display data section: You can't use a return statement in your success callback function. That data is not getting returned to your controller because your controller doesn't call the callback function. Instead, assign the response data to a controller or scope variable on success.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code that may help you.**
**Html:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices">          
      <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Enter mobile number"> <button class="remove" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">-</button>
   </fieldset>
   <button class="addfields" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add fields</button>           
   <div id="choicesDisplay">
      {{ choices }}
   </div>
</div>
```

**Js:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);    
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) { 
    $scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}, {id: 'choice2'}];      
    $scope.addNewChoice = function() {
        var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
        $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
    };

    $scope.removeChoice = function() {
        var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
        $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
    };

});
```

**Also CSS:**

```
fieldset{
    background: #FCFCFC;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #D5D5D5;
}
.addfields{
    margin: 10px 0;
}

#choicesDisplay {
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgb(227, 250, 227);
    border: 1px solid rgb(171, 239, 171);
    color: rgb(9, 56, 9);
}
.remove{
    background: #C76868;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 21px;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 9px;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 100%;   
}
input[type="text"],
select{
    padding:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<div ng-app="albumShelf">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div style="float:left;">
            <select ng-options="b.title for b in albums" ng-model="currentAlbum" ng-change="onChange()">
              <option value="">New album...</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;">
            <form>
                <input type="text" ng-model="editing.title">
                <br>
                <input type="text" ng-model="editing.artist">
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="{{ currentAlbum.title ? 'Update' : 'Save' }}" ng-click="addOrSaveAlbum()">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Js:**

```
var app= angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope/*, albumFactory*/) {
    $scope.editing = {};        
    $scope.albums = [
        { id: 1, title: 'Disorganized Fun', artist: 'Ronald Jenkees' },
        { id: 2, title: 'Secondhand Rapture', artist: 'MS MR' }
    ];
    $scope.addOrSaveAlbum = function() {
        if ($scope.currentAlbum) {
            $scope.currentAlbum.title = $scope.editing.title;
                $scope.currentAlbum.artist = $scope.editing.artist;
        }else {
            $scope.albums.push({ title: $scope.editing.title, artist: $scope.editing.artist });
        }            
            $scope.editing = {};
        };        
    $scope.onChange = function() {
        if ($scope.currentAlbum) {
            $scope.editing.title = $scope.currentAlbum.title;
            $scope.editing.artist = $scope.currentAlbum.artist;
        }else {
            $scope.editing = {};
        }
    };
}])
```

Comment: You may modify your above answer. instead of new answer.

Comment: Both are different so questionnaire can use any one of the above answers.